# Неправильный ключевой файл для таблицы

Tags: mysql

Хотелось бы узнать, что означает

> "Неправильный ключевой файл для таблицы"

Я думаю, что говорить, что это произошло при выборе данных в MySql бессмысленно, но однако хочу узнать еще и как избавиться от этого. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Данная ошибка возникает если закончилось место на жестком диске.

[Дополнительная информация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019799/mysql-incorrect-key-file-for-table-tmp-sql-185e-0-myi-try-to-repair-it#4019799).

Comment: `Неправильный ключевой файл => закончилось место на диске`. Очень логично, что тут сказать. )

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка может возникать еще при следующих условиях:

1. используются клиентские компоненты доступа к данным от Microsoft SQL Server;
2. на клиентском компьютере для доступа к SQL серверу используется протокол "Multiprotocol";
3. на SQL сервере установлен режим аутентификации "Windows only". 
   Причиной ошибки могла послужить перезагрузка SQL сервера при работающем сервере. При получении такой ошибки сервер нужно перезагрузить.  Если это все не про вас, то не знаю уж, можно на край попробовать вылечить файл.